# IOS Sound processing, level detection

Tags: ios, ios5, speech

I will be doing spun processing in IOS. While the app is running, sound is collected. When the user starts talking, a light will turn red, when they stop, it turns back to green and begins processing.

Do you have a recommendation of the best way to detect the begin and end of the speech part, and any hints on how to select that part to pass to the processing routines. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working on something similar, and I found the following resources to be quite useful:
http://mobileorchard.com/sclistener-the-easy-way-to-detect-iphone-microphone-sound-levels/
http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/